Typescript .push of custom class not working?
The point of this typescript function is to separate the initial array results and add them to their respective arrays nased on their type, I can't see how this doesn't work?

I push in a array of IClientSearch
Then I use a forEach to individually separate each value
Then I use if statements to see which client type each result is  is (clientType is a enum here and the if else statements work)
And finally the result should be pushed into the existing array I created?

Can anyone see something I am missing?
typescript file
clientsA: IClientSearch[] = [];
clientsB: IClientSearch[] = [];
clientsC: IClientSearch[] = [];

getAllClients(query: any) {
  this.apiDataService.getAllClients(query).subscribe((data: IClientSearch[]) => {
    data.forEach(i => {
      if (i.clientType == 0) {
        this.clientsA.push(i);
      }
      else if (i.clientType == 1) {
        this.clientsB.push(i);
      }
      else if (i.clientType == 2) {
        this.clientsC.push(i);
      }
      else {
        console.log(i);
      }
    });
  }
}

IClientSearch
export interface IClientSearch {
  name: any;
  number: any;
  address1: any;
  city: any;
  postcode: any;
  country: any;
  clientType: ClientType;
}

export enum ClientType {
  A = 0,
  B = 1,
  C = 2
}

I've tried using .push and can't find anything else that works. Previously this was just this.clientA = data but I need to separate the results.

The console.log should be outside of the if conditions.

(1) You use an enum and then proceed to use 0/1/2 in code instead of the enum...? Use ClientType.A etc. I'm pretty sure you get a TypeScript error there. (2) You should always be using strict equality ===, especially with TypeScript. What's the point of TypeScript if you're gonna allow willy-nilly type coercion anyways? (3) TypeScript enums are kinda bad and have nowhere enough functionality as they do in other languages. I would just use 0 | 1 | 2 or a union of string literals for readability if you're gonna stick to not using the enum when comparing. (1/2)

(4) You should be using discriminated unions for the best type hints here. (5) Consider not typing everything as any if you can help it in IClientSearch. (2/2)

@MB_18 the console log was for testing so yeah it should be removed

@mochaccino thanks for helping with the more general issues (I have implemented these now) but this hasn't fixed the issue I'm having using .push

So I found a solution where I created new arrays of the same type inside the method then cast them to the existing arrays.
clientsA: IClientSearch[] = [];
clientsB: IClientSearch[] = [];
clientsC: IClientSearch[] = [];

this.apiDataService.getAllClients(query).subscribe((data: IClientSearch[]) => {
  let a: IClientSearch[] = [];
  let b: IClientSearch[] = [];
  let c: IClientSearch[] = [];

  data.forEach(i => {
    if (i.clientType === ClientType.A) {
      a.push(i);
    }
    else if (i.clientType === ClientType.B) {
      b.push(i);
    }
    else if (i.clientType === ClientType.C) {
      c.push(i);
    }
  });

  this.clientsA = a;
  this.clientsB = b;
  this.clientsC = c;
  }
}

